# how can I read from a USB device without knowing the device name?

Tags: command-line, usb, c, devices

I have an Arturia, MiniLab, it is a serial, non block device. I would like to read keypresses from the device, but I cant figure out where the `/dev/device` is that I should read key presses from. I would like to know how I can use information like output from `lsusb` to then listen to the USB device.  `lsusb ... Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c75:0204 Arturia Arturia MINILAB`

is there a way I can find the device name from the ID field? or read data from the USB connection without knowing the device name in /dev? given what I know, what is my next step to reading data from the USB device?

Comment: You might be able to see the /dev/??? with `tail -f /var/log/syslog` as you insert the device. Get out of tail with Ctrl+c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information provided by `lsusb` should be enough to work out the `/dev` location, as everything connected via USB will be readable from `/dev/bus/usb/{bus}/{device}`.

Here is the output of `lsusb` on my notebook, which — for the sake of this example — has a wireless mouse dongle and a Canon DSLR camera attached via USB.

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0097 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5ce Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5cf Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated IR Camera
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04a9:3270 Canon, Inc. EOS 100D
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The dongle for the mouse is at `Bus 001 Device 007`, so this means I can query/probe it from `/dev/bus/usb/001/007`.

If you would like to get more information about a USB device, you can also use `usb-devices` from the terminal. This will output information about data transmission rates, power limits, serial numbers and the like. For the mouse's dongle, I get this:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=02 Dev#=  7 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=32 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=045e ProdID=07fd Rev=03.15
S:  Manufacturer=Microsoft
S:  Product=Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
```

This also confirms that the device is connected to Bus 1 as Device 7 along the top line.

If you're looking for something that might help with debugging a device, then `dmesg` may be what you're looking for. Again, for the mouse's dongle, I see this in the output:

```
[208483.802953] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[208483.955942] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=07fd, bcdDevice= 3.15
[208483.955944] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[208483.955945] usb 1-2: Product: Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1
[208483.955946] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[208483.985246] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[208483.985247] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[208483.999278] input: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/0003:045E:07FD.0001/input/input19
[208484.059311] hid-generic 0003:045E:07FD.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
[208484.059641] input: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:045E:07FD.0002/input/input20
[208484.119192] input: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:045E:07FD.0002/input/input21
[208484.119309] input: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1/0003:045E:07FD.0002/input/input22
[208484.119483] hid-generic 0003:045E:07FD.0002: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
[208484.119645] input: Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2/0003:045E:07FD.0003/input/input23
[208484.178991] hid-generic 0003:045E:07FD.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft Nano Transceiver 1.1] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input2
```

This will give you specific input pointers, which are useful if you're writing code that directly interfaces with the hardware, such as a device driver.

Hope this gives you the information you're looking for.